# HTML5 drag and drop files: Cannot drag drop files from a ftp server?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I want to drag and drop files into my HTML site. I have the code working perfect with local files to drag/drop. But when I try to drag/drop files into the site from FTP server, I get 0 files in my app. 
Is this not achievable?

Comment: I don't think this could easily be fixed, but someone smarter than me might prove me wrong. But to me, it looks like something that should be fixed by the FTP-client  and not by your HTML.